# User defined Python 3.2.2 problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions

When I run the following code, the result is nothing whatever I set the absoluteValue to. Why?

```
def absoluteValue(n):
     if (n) < 0:
         return -(n)
     elif (n) > 0:
         return (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly on my system while using Python 3.2.2:

```
>>> def absoluteValue(n):
     if (n) < 0:
         return -(n)
     elif (n) > 0:
         return (n)

>>> absoluteValue(-34)
34
>>> absoluteValue(34)
34
>>>
```

Check if you have installed python properly.

Comment: Oh, it now works if I do it on the IDLE but not on the main interpreter. Thanks anyway!